While using AWK, I'd like to verify that the NF is >= 10. If not, write the line to a reject file
I have an AWK script that is embedded in BASH code.
cat MyFile.csv | awk -v reject_file=MyRejectFile.csv "${AWK_SCRIPT}" | <generic loader>

And here is my AWK_SCRIPT...
   AWK_SCRIPT='BEGIN {
   FS=","
   OFS=","
   }
   {
      if (NF < 10) {
         print $0 >> reject_file
      }
   print $0
   }
   '

MyFile.csv looks something like this...
This,is,a,sample,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields
This,line,has,less,than,10,fields
This,is,a,second,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields
This,line,also,has,less,than,10,fields

I am trying to get the first and third lines to print to stdout and the second and fourth lines to print to the reject file.

Almost there! Just add next in the if

... or use an else statement

An else statement and double-quote "reject_file" to make clear that isn't an awk-variable. If it is, then leave as is. print is all you need. print $0 is superfluous, but doesn't hurt. By default the entire record is printed.

@DavidC.Rankin reject_file is a variable, defined by a command-line argument.

Okay, missed that, then awk 'BEGIN { FS="," OFS="," } { if (NF < 10) { print >> reject_file } else { print } }' yourdata.txt

GNU awk knows what CSV files are (-k option). If your awk is GNU: awk -v rf=MyRejectFile.csv -k 'NF<10 {print > rf} NF>=10' MyFile.csv.

@RenaudPacalet please keep in mind that -k is relatively recent addition to GNU awk and therefore might be unavailable if installed awk is older version

Storing your awk script in a variable makes your code harder to implement and harder to read. Why are you doing that?

You probably want print $0 > reject_file instead of print $0 >> reject_file. The semantics of { print $0 > reject_file} in awk is the same as while read line; do echo "$line"; done > reject_file in shell, not while read line; do echo "$line" > reject_file; done.

There's a few ways to skin this cat:
You could use an else:
   AWK_SCRIPT='BEGIN {
   FS=","
   OFS=","
   }
   {
      if (NF < 10) {
         print $0 >> reject_file
      }
      else {
         print $0
      }
   }
   '

You could also just drop next inside the if block to stop processing the current line and skip to the next line:
   AWK_SCRIPT='BEGIN {
   FS=","
   OFS=","
   }
   {
      if (NF < 10) {
         print $0 >> reject_file
         next
      }
   print $0
   }
   '

You could also just spell out each condition and resulting action:
   AWK_SCRIPT='BEGIN {
   FS=","
   OFS=","
   }
   NF < 10 {
      print $0 >> reject_file
   }
   NF >= 10 {
      print $0
   }
   '


I went with the if/else 1st approach because it is cleaner and easier to read in my opinion. Thank you for the solution!

Try this:
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
NF<10{print $0 > "reject_file"; next}
1
' file    

If you use >> the lines are appended to the file if existing where > deletes the file if existing.

reject_file is a variable in the OPs code, it's just hard to see that because they're storing the whole awk script in a variable.

You may use this awk solution that does it in a single print statement:
awk -F, '{out = (NF < 10 ? "rejectFile" : "/dev/stdout"); print > out}' file

This,is,a,sample,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields
This,is,a,second,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields

cat rejectFile
This,line,has,less,than,10,fields
This,line,also,has,less,than,10,fields


Just mention that requires GNU awk, BWK awk or mawk for a string "/dev/stdout" meaning stdout. I don't know if any other awk supports that but it's not POSIX, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Special-FD.

Hmm I tested it on my Mac and it worked with Mac supplied awk as well which is BSD awk I believe

There may just happen to be a file named /dev/stdout on Macs that you can write to in that way and see the result on stdout but AFAIK BSD awks don't map the string "/dev/stdout" to whatever the stdout file descriptor happens to be on that system, unlike the 3 awk versions I mentioned.

Yes on mac /dev/stdout is a symbolic link to /dev/fd/1 file.

Using any awk:
$ awk -v reject_file=MyRejectFile.csv -F, '
    { print | ( "cat>" (NF<10 ? reject_file : "&1") ) }
' MyFile.csv
This,is,a,sample,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields
This,is,a,second,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields


$ cat MyRejectFile.csv
This,line,has,less,than,10,fields
This,line,also,has,less,than,10,fields


With a recent GNU awk (which knows what CSV files are):
awk -v rf=MyRejectFile.csv -k 'NF<10 {print > rf} NF>=10' MyFile.csv


A minimalist approach:
awk -F, 'NF>9;NF<10{print>"reject_file"}' MyFile.csv

stdout
This,is,a,sample,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields
This,is,a,second,line,that,has,more,than,10,fields

reject_file
This,line,has,less,than,10,fields
This,line,also,has,less,than,10,fields


4 concise awk approaches :

Saving the boolean outcome of the pattern, and printing its inverse to /dev/stdout :
awk -F, '_ = NF < 10 { print >(__) } !_' __='MyRejectFile.csv' MyFile.csv 


Pairing the flipped pattern with an implicit { print } action block :
awk -F, 'NF < 10 { print >(__) } 9 < NF' __='MyRejectFile.csv' MyFile.csv 


Clearing $0 via NF = 0 after printing to the reject file, so only its complement set will get printed to /dev/stdout :
awk -F, 'NF < 10 { print >(__)
                   NF = 0 } NF' __='MyRejectFile.csv' MyFile.csv 


Using a custom function in lieu of action blocks. The lack of return value from the function means NF will be set to blank (""), i.e. zero :
awk -F, 'function _() { print >(__) } 9 < NF ||
             NF = _()' __='MyRejectFile.csv' MyFile.csv 



